# Find out whose using Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

We have one Redis for our company and multiple teams are using it. We are getting a surge of requests and nobody seems to know which application is causing it. We have only one password that goes around the whole company and our Redis is secured under a VPN so we know it's not coming from the outside.

Is there a way to know whose using Redis? Maybe we can pass in some headers with the connection from every app to identify who makes the most requests, etc.

We use Spring Data Redis for our communication.

Comment: Just use `redis-cli monitor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is too broad since different strategies can be used here:

1. Use [Redis MONITOR](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) command. This is basically a built-in debugging tool that monitors all the commands executed by Redis

2. Use some kind of intermediate proxy. Instead of routing all the commands directly to redis - route everything to proxy that will do some processing like measuring the amounts of commands by the calling host or maybe types of commands depending what you want.
   This is still only a configuration related solution so you won't need any changes at the level of applications
3. Since you have spring boot, you can use Micrometer / metering integration. This way you could create a counter / gauge that will get updated upon each request to Redis. If you also stream the metering data to tools like Prometheus, you'll be able to create a dashboard, say in grafana to see the whole picture. Micrometer can integrate also with other products, Prometheus/Grafana was only an example, you can chose any other solution (maybe in your organization you already have something like that).

Comment: Also, [`CLIENT LIST`](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) can be helpful here

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! I have a library that is used to connect to Redis, and upon initializing the client, I'd ask them a 'team/app name'. Later, on every request, I'd send the logs to the influxDB and see graphs in Grafana! Thank you Mark :)